# Faster option switch in GRUB

Tags: grub2

I recently dual booted Windows 10 with Ubuntu and everything worked fine. I have just a problem with GRUB and I wonder how it can be fixed. When I have to select the options (Ubuntu, Windows Boot Loader, Advanced etc) it takes some time to switch between those lines. It’s a delay estimated to 3 seconds before the next line is highlighted so I can press “Enter”. Is there any way to make it faster?